# Code Error 800A0409 - Unterminated String Constant (Japanese Windows)

Tags: vbscript

This one is kind of strange to me. Prior to posting I did research this error code and according to many articles out there it seems relatively a straight forward issue. The issue is generally related to either missing double quotes in a string or where a string spans across multiple lines.

However, in my case neither of the above seem to be the cause of the issue. The strange thing is my code works fine in English windows operating system but I encounter this error only in the Japanese version of windows.

[image]

The error is pointing to the following line of code:

```vb
WScript.Echo "PFXファイル " & pfxFileName & " は存在しません。"
```

Any ideas why this would only happen in the Japanese version of Windows?

Here is the block of surrounding code in case it gives any further clues:

```vb
' check if pfx file exists
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
pfxFileExists = 0
Do
  If fso.FileExists(pfxFilePath & pfxFileName) Then
    ' it exists, continue
    pfxFileExists = 1 
  Else
    ' The PFX file does not exist.
    WScript.Echo "PFXファイル " & pfxFileName & " は存在しません。"
  End If
Loop Until pfxFileExists = 1
```

Comment: same error if you try `MsgBox "PFXファイル "` and `MsgBox " は存在しません。"` ? My guess is the `。` at the end but that can be tested if you output them one by one.

Comment: Is the script saved in Unicode format?